# Как сделать * не обязательным аргументом

Tags: discord.py

у меня есть команда анонса, но у меня вопрос, как сделать * не обязательным аргументом
`async def __anons(ctx, time, *, message=None):`
то есть чтобы его значение по умолчанию было None, просто прописывать  *=None нельзя
Там просто много вариантов, где * нужна, и где * не нужна, такие как эти:
Испорченный телефон - где * нужна
Мафия - где * не нужна

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ничего не понятно, * здесь это вообще не аргумент...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты хоть понимаешь что эта звездочка там вообще делает?  Никакого аргумента через  одиночную * никуда не передается.  Она используется просто для того, чтобы аргументы после неё были только именованные.
То есть со звёздочкой обязательно надо будет вызов делать так

```
        __anons(ctx, time, message="мой текст" )
```

без неё же можно

```
        __anons(ctx, time, message)
```

и

```
        __anons(ctx, time, message="мой текст" )
```

То есть будет три позиционных аргумента без неё.